# SQL - How X in SELECT X, AGG(Z) OVER (PARTITION X) is handled in analytics SQL

Tags: sql, analytics

**Question**

In `SELECT` SQL using analytics function(s)

```
SELECT 
    X, AGG_FUNCTION(Z) OVER (PARTITION X ORDER BY Y) 
FROM 
    T
```

how is the column `X` in the `SELECT` corelated to `X` in the `PARTITION BY` clause?

Example table

```
Name                  Null?    Type           
--------------------- -------- -------------- 
STUDENT_ID            NOT NULL NUMBER(8)      
SECTION_ID            NOT NULL NUMBER(8)      
GRADE_TYPE_CODE       NOT NULL CHAR(2)        <--- This is X column
NUMERIC_GRADE         NOT NULL NUMBER(3)
```

Excerpt of the table

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    student_id,
    section_id,
    grade_type_code,
    numeric_grade
FROM
    grade;
```

[image]

In the example below, the `grade_type_code` is the `X` column. Apparently `grade_type_code` is related to the `grade_type_code` in `PARTITION BY` clause.

```
query = """
SELECT DISTINCT
    grade_type_code,   <---- How this 'grade_type_code' is related to that in PARTITION BY clause?
    MAX(numeric_grade) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_type_code) as maximum,
    MIN(numeric_grade) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_type_code) as minimum,
    ROUND(AVG(numeric_grade) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_type_code),2) as mean,
    ROUND(VARIANCE(numeric_grade) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_type_code),2) as var,
    ROUND(STDDEV(numeric_grade) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_type_code),2) as std,
    COUNT(numeric_grade) OVER (PARTITION BY grade_type_code) as cnt
FROM
    grade
ORDER BY
    grade_type_code
"""
spark.sql(query).show(truncate=False)

+---------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----+---+
|grade_type_code|maximum|minimum|mean |var  |std |cnt|
+---------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----+---+
|FI             |99     |76     |85.77|46.99|6.86|205|
|HM             |99     |70     |86.12|67.27|8.2 |798|
|MT             |99     |76     |87.08|43.15|6.57|204|
|PA             |99     |70     |86.32|56.43|7.51|394|
|PJ             |99     |76     |87.0 |48.2 |6.94|21 |
|QZ             |99     |73     |86.75|59.97|7.74|382|
+---------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----+---+
```

I believe that something similar to correlated subquery is happening inside the SQL engine. The SQL engine finds `grade_type_code` column in SELECT statement, and check if it exists in the PARITION BY clause. If exists, the value of the `grade_type_code` is applied in the PARTITION BY part.

Because when tested the same using the GROUP BY SQL below, the result matches. The aggregation functions work on respective group created by `GROUP BY grade_type_code` specific to a grade_type_code value. I believe the same happens with `SELECT X, AGG_FUNCTION(Z) OVER (PARTITION X ORDER BY Y) FROM T`.

```
query = """
SELECT 
    grade_type_code,     <----- column X
    MAX(numeric_grade) as maximum,
    MIN(numeric_grade) as minimum,
    ROUND(AVG(numeric_grade),2) as mean,
    ROUND(VARIANCE(numeric_grade), 2) as var,
    ROUND(STDDEV(numeric_grade), 2) as std,
    COUNT(*) as cnt
FROM
    grade
GROUP BY
    grade_type_code
ORDER BY 
    grade_type_code
"""
spark.sql(query).show(truncate=False)

+---------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----+---+
|grade_type_code|maximum|minimum|mean |var  |std |cnt|
+---------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----+---+
|FI             |99     |76     |85.77|46.99|6.86|205|
|HM             |99     |70     |86.12|67.27|8.2 |798|
|MT             |99     |76     |87.08|43.15|6.57|204|
|PA             |99     |70     |86.32|56.43|7.51|394|
|PJ             |99     |76     |87.0 |48.2 |6.94|21 |
|QZ             |99     |73     |86.75|59.97|7.74|382|
+---------------+-------+-------+-----+-----+----+---+
```

Please advise if my understanding is correct, and provide pointers to resource which explain this mechanism in detail if any.

Answer (score 0):

The analytical or window functions do not require column from "partition by" part to present in the "select" part of the statement below.

Here are some examples in the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-syntax-qry-select-window.html)

The "partition by" just says to the function: "now, start calculating sum (avg, count, whatever) starting from 0 for that group ".

There are 2 reasons why you get same results with analytical and group functions:

- there are only analytical function in the select with same partition by criteria. This will result identical rows for every value of grade_type_code (for example, there will be 3 identical rows for grade_type_code = QZ)
- there is the "distinct" which eliminates duplicate rows